# Apache Proxy Using Secure Connection

Tags: apache, ssl, https, proxy

So i have an apache forward proxy setup like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

        AddRadiusAuth **radius server ip**:1812 **secret** 5:3

        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyVia On
        AllowConnect 443 5601


        <Proxy "*">
                Order Deny,Allow
                Allow from all
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Please Enter Your JumpCloud Credentials"
                AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
                AuthRadiusAuthoritative on
                AuthBasicProvider radius
                AuthRadiusActive On
                Require valid-user
        </Proxy>



        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_forward_proxy.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_forward_proxy.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

now whenever a user tries to connect to the radius server he is allowed to login without any issues, BUT, the user gets this message when trying to login:

[this image shows what the user sees when he tries to login using his radius credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWPUs.png)

Now that is not exactly safe because since the proxy connection is not private if anyone is eavesdropping on the connection the attacker can see the user and pass and eventually hack our systems.

How can i make the connection private and secured. I tried enabling SSL module and using a certificate file using these

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/vpn.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/vpn.key
```

outside of the proxy tags but that didnt work, if i put them inside the proxy tags i get an error saying that they're not allowed to be there, so what am i missing here?

Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Regards!

Comment: It should be outside proxy tags. What exactly "that didnt work" means, any errors in log or in browser?

Comment: what i meant by "that didn't work" is that, it didn't make the connection private instead it gave me another error: "400 Bad Request" when i tried to go to an HTTP site and an "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error when i tried to go to an HTTPS site

Comment: it doesnt even prompt the user to enter his user and pass